Is there relationship between PPI of mobilephone and resolution of the image taken by it?
My smartphone's display info:
Size    6.53 inches, 102.9 cm2 (~81.0% screen-to-body ratio)
Resolution  720 x 1600 pixels, 20:9 ratio (~269 ppi density)

The ppi is 269,now i take a photo with it,upload it into my computer,open it with gimp,it shows that  image size is 4160*3120,resolution(ppi) is 72.Why the resolution is not 269 as described ?

Are you talking about the display of the phone or the camera sensor? Those are two very different things... PPI is Pixels Per Inch, so 720x1600 display in a 6.53 inch package would be about 269 pixels per inch in that form factor... the 4160x3120 size being 72ppi honestly depends on the medium, the 72ppi is the "standard" and comes from back in the 1980's when monitors had literally 72 pixels per inch... it is kind of a myth that just hangs around now. So are you talking about the display or the pictures you took?

@acejavelin AFAICS, that's what the OP got confused about; that display resolution depends on the medium, not on the image.
